# Using a Prism PubSub style event in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, prism, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to create an event aggregator in C++/CLI, I know that the valid syntax in C# would be as follows:

```
//C# code
public partial class Foo : UserControl, IView, IDisposable
{
    private IEventAggregator _aggregator;

    public Foo(IEventAggregator aggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._aggregator = aggregator;
        if (this._aggregator == null)
            throw new Exception("null pointer");

        _subToken =_aggregator.GetEvent<fooEvent>().Subscribe(Handler, ThreadOption.UIThread, false);
    }

    private SubscriptionToken _subToken = null;

    private void Handler(fooEventPayload args)
    {
        //this gets run on the event
    }
}
```

However directly converting this to C++/CLI gives the error "a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class" on the indicated line. Is there a workaround? I think it has something to do with how C# generates "Action".

```
//C++/CLI code
ref class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(IEventAggregator^ aggregator)
    {
        void InitializeComponent();

        this->_aggregator = aggregator;
        if (this->_aggregator == nullptr)
            throw gcnew Exception("null pointer");

        //error in the following line on Hander, a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class
        _subToken = _aggregator->GetEvent<fooEvent^>()->Subscribe(Handler, ThreadOption::UIThread, false); 
private:
    IEventAggregator ^ _aggregator;
    SubscriptionToken ^ _addActorPipelineToken = nullptr;

    void Handler(fooEventPayload^ args)
    {
        //this gets run on the event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly instantiate the delegate object, rather than allowing C# to do this for you.

```
_subToken = _aggregator->GetEvent<fooEvent^>()->Subscribe(
    gcnew Action<fooEventPayload^>(this, &Foo::Handler), ThreadOption::UIThread, false); 
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     Explicitly instantiate the delegate.
//                                 ^^^^                Object to call the delegate on.
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ C++-style reference to the method.
```